# Laravel - Eloquent relationship (hasMany) issues

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

Yet another eloquent relationship issue :) I hope somebody can help me out!

**ProductionOrder.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ProductionOrder extends Model
{  
    public function workOrders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\WorkOrder');
    }
}
```

**WorkOrder.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class WorkOrder extends Model
{
    public function productionOrder()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\ProductionOrder');
    }
}
```

So a ProductionOrder should have one or more WorkOrders.

**Production order migration**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('production_orders', function (Blueprint $table) 
    {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('production_order_id')->unique();
        $table->longText('notes')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
     });
}
```

**Work order migration**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('work_orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('work_order_id')->unique();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('production_order_id'); 
     });
 }
```

The reason the ID names are not just 'id' is because i am importing the order data from a external API. I think this is the reason why the relationship does not work but I can't seem to fix it.

```
ProductionOrder::with('workOrders')->get();
```

The above returns an empty array in the `work_orders` attribute for each production order, however there are definitely work orders located in the database with existing `production_order_id`.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it, had to add two times the `production_order_id` to the `hasMany` relationship:

```
 public function workOrders()
 {
     return $this->hasMany('App\WorkOrder', 'production_order_id', 'production_order_id');
 }
```

Comment: this is not adding two time. you are explicitly mentioning your related columns(keys) in the relation. by default it will take `id` instead of 'production_order_id` . so here you mentioned that dont take `id`, take `production_order_id`.

Answer (score -2):

use query like this you will get data surely

```
 class ProductionOrder extends Model
    {  
        public function workOrders()
        {
            //use this
            //return $this->hasMany(WorkOrder::class, 'id of workorder table which forigne key of', 'primary key of this table');
 return $this->hasMany(WorkOrder::class, 'production_order_id', 'id');

//instead of
            //return $this->hasMany('App\WorkOrder');
        }
    }

ProductionOrder::where('production_order_id', '=', 70600)->with('workOrders')->first();
```

Comment: please add-relation key according to i suggest and let me know i sure this will work